# Incompatible types. Required: android.content.Context Found: java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to get device id using Secure.getString()

I am using context

```
 public static String getDeviceId(Context context) {
        String currentDeviceId = SharedPreferencesUtil.getCurrentDeviceId();
        if (currentDeviceId == null) {
            context = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "android_id");
            if (context == null || context.trim().isEmpty() || "9774d56d682e549c".equalsIgnoreCase(context)) {
                context = Build.SERIAL;
                if (context == null || context.trim().isEmpty() != null) {
                    context = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                } else {
                    context = Build.SERIAL;
                }
            }
            if ("unknown".equals(context)) {
                context = Build.SERIAL;
                if (context == null || context.trim().isEmpty() != null) {
                    context = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                } else {
                    context = Build.SERIAL;
                }
            }
            secondDeviceId = context;
```

This line showing below error

```
context = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "android_id");
```

> Incompatible types.
>   Required:
>   android.content.Context
>   Found:
>   java.lang.String

Comment: [The method exists](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#getString(android.content.ContentResolver,%252520java.lang.String)). Double check you parameters.

Comment: Why are you assigning to the parameter ```context```, and not creating a new variable, e.g. ```String deviceId = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "android_id");```?

Comment: Because I am debugging an application @vlumi

Comment: The ```getString``` method returns a ```String```, which you cannot assign to a variable of type ```Context```. You are treating it as a ```String``` after the assignment...

Comment: Thank you @vlumi, for your comment and support. I too did some debugging and fixed it will post answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @vlumi comment and my debugging I found following code to fix this.
It is fixed now, just need to replace context with string.

```
public static String getDeviceId(Context paramContext) {
        String localObject = SharedPreferencesUtil.getCurrentDeviceId();
        if (localObject == null) {
            String str1 = Settings.Secure.getString(paramContext.getContentResolver(), "android_id");
            if ((str1 == null) || (str1.trim().isEmpty()) || ("9774d56d682e549c".equalsIgnoreCase(str1)))
            {
                String str2 = Build.SERIAL;
                if ((str2 != null) && (!str2.trim().isEmpty())) {
                    str1 = Build.SERIAL;
                } else {
                    str1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                }
            }
            if ("unknown".equals(str1))
            {
                String str3 = Build.SERIAL;
                if ((str3 != null) && (!str3.trim().isEmpty())) {
                    str1 = Build.SERIAL;
                } else {
                    str1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                }
            }
            secondDeviceId = str1;
```